# How to loop chained calls elegantly in JavaScript/CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, dry

I'm using [Soda](https://github.com/learnboost/soda) to write Selenium tests in Node.js and I have a situation where I have to press the down key several times.

The code currently looks like this:

```
browser                                                                     
  .chain                                                                    
  .setSpeed(200)                                                            
  .session()                                                                
  .open('/')                                                                
  .click("id=save")                                                         
  .focus(editor)                                                            
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
  .keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  

  ...
```

How could I DRY this up?

Just using a loop like this does not work with this lib:

```
var b = browser.chain()                                                     
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                                              
  b.keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                 
}
```

Awesome ideas?

I could use the async API in Soda and for example [async-lib](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help me out, but that's not what I'm asking here. It makes some other things ugly.

Comment: What does the loop actually do?  One keydown?

Comment: Try moving `chain` inside the loop, as in `b.chain.keyDown`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method called `and` for doing complicated things in the middle of a command chain:

```
browser
  .chain
  .setSpeed(200)
  .session()
  .open('/')
  .click("id=save")
  .focus(editor)
  .and(function (browser) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      browser.keyDown(editor, '\\40')
    }
  })
  ...
```

See the README for more information: https://github.com/learnboost/soda

Comment: Ah, I totally missed this! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Did you try replacing the `b` variable in your loop?

```
var b = browser.chain()                                                     
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                                              
  b = b.keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close. You just have to change b in the loop so it chains correctly.

```
var b = browser.chain()                                                      
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                                               
  b = b.keyDown(editor, '\\40')                                                  
}
```