# d3.js - Number of calls to .key controlled by an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm developing a simple project in d3.js and the data I have is flat json, like this:

```
[
 {"A":A,
  "B":B
  } ... ]
```

I want to develop a function that structures this into an hierarchical json object. The problem is that in my project the number of levels of the data is not constant, so I might have more keys for a dataset than for another. First I thought about chaining the .key in a cycle, sort of like this: [How to loop chained calls elegantly in JavaScript/CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557093/how-to-loop-chained-calls-elegantly-in-javascript-coffeescript) but I'm assuming that's something specific of soda and I'm not finding an equivalent for d3.

Then I thought about creating a cycle where I would cycle through the array with the keys and add one at a time. The code I was trying was this one:

```
var parser = function(data){

    var arrKeys = d3.keys(data[0]);
    var keys = arrKeys.filter(function(arr) {
                                return arr.slice(0,1) !== 'V'})
    var rollups = arrKeys.filter(function(arr) {
                                return arr.slice(0,1)  == 'V'})
    var expensesByName = d3.nest()

    for(i = 0; i< keys.length;i++) {
        expensesByName = expensesByName.key(function(d) { console.log(d[keys[i]]); return d[keys[i]]}); }

    expensesByName = expensesByName.rollup(function(v) { return {
    total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d[rollups][0]; })
    }}).entries(data);

}
```

(v indicates that that's a variable to sum or count and not a key)

The problem here is that I don't know how to pass the keys array to the function. I've tried to call function(d, keys) with no success and I don't think I can pass an external variable inside the method.

So now I'm not sure where to turn to. Can I keep this approach but changing something? Do I need to find a completely new approach to this? What is your suggestion to make this work?

EDIT: The data is something like this:

```
[{root: "root",
  brand: "brand1",
  zone: "zone1",
  store: "store1",
  expenses: 234234},
 ...]
```

I want to turn this into something like this:

```
[{key: "root", values:
    {key: "brand", values:
        {key: "zone", values:
            {key: "store", values:
                {key: "expenses", value: 234234}}}}}]
```

EDIT 2: Let's assume that for one specific set of brands it is done like the example above. Something like:

```
[{root: "root",
      brand: "brand1",
      zone: "zone1",
      store: "store1",
      Vexpenses: 234234},
      {root: "root",
      brand: "brand1",
      zone: "zone1",
      store: "store3",
      Vexpenses: 234232},
     {root: "root",
      brand: "brand2",
      zone: "zone1",
      store: "store1",
      Vexpenses: 234291},
      {root: "root",
      brand: "brand1",
      zone: "zone2",
      store: "store3",
      Vexpenses: 234232}]
```

However, for a different set of stores, the zone is not considered, so my data would be something like:

```
[{root: "root",
      brand: "brand1",
      store: "store1",
      Vexpenses: 234234},
      {root: "root",
      brand: "brand1",
      store: "store3",
      Vexpenses: 234232},
     {root: "root",
      brand: "brand2",
      store: "store1",
      Vexpenses: 234291},
      {root: "root",
      brand: "brand1",
      store: "store3",
      Vexpenses: 234232}]
```

I want to create a function able to map both of the possibilities (in the format shown above) without hardcoding.

Comment: it is unclear what kind of data you have (need more lines) and what the result is you want based on the example data

Comment: @rioV8 post update with more info :)

Comment: determining what needs to be done based on a single records is impossible, expand the example to 4 or more records, in the example are no keys that start with `V`

Comment: @rioV8 editied with more info